Page could not refresh after router.push in Next JS
"use client"
const handleYearChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
     e.preventDefault() 

     const year = e.target.value

     startTransition(() => {
        router.push(`${path}?year=${year}`)
     })

     setInterval(() => {
        router.refresh()
     }, 1000)
}

<select name="year-range" onChange={(e) => handleYearChange(e)}>
     {announcementData.map((data: any, index: number) => {
         return (
            <option value={data.year} key={index}>
               {data.year}
            </option>
         )
     })}
</select>

I have an issue in Next JS Project that I could not refresh the page after pushing the route when selecting another options in dropdown menu. What I tried is router.refresh() does not work and the component is use client so is there any possible solutions to fix?
